# Getting Conclusion: don't install symfony/console v4.4 while upgrade Magento 2.4.1 from Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3, magento2.4.1, magento-upgrade, composer-update

I am trying to upgrade my Magento 2.3.3 to Magento 2.4.1
running the below commands.

> 1.composer require magento/composer-root-update-plugin=~1.0 --no-update
>
> 2.composer update
>
> 3.composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.4.1 --no-update
>
> 4.composer update

after this step i get this error

[image]

I have tried this thing but not getting anything

```
composer require symfony/config:4.1.*

composer require symfony/dependency-injection:3.3.*

composer update
```

*`composer require --dev phpunit/phpunit:~6.2.0 friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer:~2.10.1 lusitanian/oauth:~0.8.10 pdepend/pdepend:2.5.2 sebastian/phpcpd:~3.0.0 squizlabs/php_codesniffer:3.2.2 --no-update`*

Answer (score 1):

The magento/data-migration-tool version needs updating to match the magento version that you're updating to. That should remedy the version conflict.

Comment: solved my problem thank you!